# Converting closed form to recursive and recursive to closed form

Tags: recurrence-relations

Please explain to me how to convert this to closed form:

$$P_n = 1.75P_{n-1}, P_0=40.$$

And how to convert these into recursive form:

$$
\begin{align*}
Y &= 5.4x-27, \\
Y &= 3800\cdot1.04^x.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We will begin to calculate, to see what is going on.

We have $P_0=40$.  Therefore, by the given recurrence, $P_1=(1.75)P_0=(1.75)(40)$.

**Important:** Don't plug $(1.75)(40)$ into a calculator!  In fact, to prevent the temptation, I will write instead $P_1=(1.75)P_0$.  We want to be always aware of the **structure** of our answer, and plugging numbers into a calculator tends to hide structure.

What is $P_2$?  by the recurrence, it is $(1.75)P_1$.  But $P_1=(1.75)P_0$, so
$P_2=(1.75)(1.75)P_0$.  For convenience write instead $P_2=(1.75)^2P_0$.

What is $P_3$?  By the recurrence, $P_3=(1.75)P_2$.  But from our expression for $P_2$, we get $P_3=(1.75)(1.75)^2P_0$, which is $(1.75)^3P_0$.

Maybe compute a bit further. Or not.  It is I think clear that the same reasoning will give $P_4=(1.75)^4P_0$, and in general $P_n=(1.75)^nP_0$ for any non-negative integer $n$.  So we conclude that
$$P_n=((1.75)^n)(40).$$

Now let's look at your $Y=5.4x -27$.  Presumably the intent is that $x$ is a non-negative integer. In order to bring out the analogies with the first problem, I will write $n$ instead of $x$.  So $Y=5.4n-27$.  Note that $Y$ depends on $n$.  Bring out this dependence by writing instead
$$Y_n=5.4n -27.$$

Note that $Y_0=-27$.  What is $Y_1$?  It is $5.4$ more than $Y_0$.  So $Y_1=5.4+Y_0$.

What is $Y_2$?  From the formula, it is $(2)(5.4)-27$.  Note that this is $5.4$ more than $Y_1$.  And what is $Y_3$? It is $(3)(5.4)-27$, which is $5.4$ more than $Y_2$.  It is clear that $Y_4$ is $5.4$ more than $Y_3$, and that in general $Y_n$ is $5.4$ more than $Y_{n-1}$.

We reach the conclusion that $Y_n=Y_{n-1}+5.4$, with $Y_0=-27$.

We could proceed slightly more abstractly.  Note that $Y_n=5.4n-27$ and that $Y_{n-1}=5.4(n-1)-27$.  Subtract.  After a bit of algebra, we get $Y_n-Y_{n-1}=5.4$, or equivalently $Y_n=Y_{n-1}+5.4$.

Finally, we look at the equation that you wrote as
$$Y=3800(1.04)^x$$

Again, I imagine $x$ is supposed to be a non-negative integer.  I will keep the $x$, though I am tempted to replace it by $n$.  But definitely, "$Y$" is not good, we should write it either as $Y_x$ or $Y(x)$, to make explicit the dependence on $x$.

So we have 
$$Y_x=3800(1.04)^x$$
Now look at my discussion of the first question you had.  What was the *answer* to that?  And what was the *question*?  In our current problem, the question looks like the answer to the first problem we dealt with.

Or more directly, we have from the given equation that $Y_0=3800$.  Can you see that to get the "next" $Y$, you multiply the current $Y$ by $1.04$? So $Y_x=(1.04)Y_{x-1}$.

Comment: (Just pointing out two typos, but you're missing a $ about halfway through and you have a comma pretending to be a decimal at the very end.)

Comment: @El'endia Starman:  Thank you for pointing out the typos. Hope I have fixed them. I am typo-prone.  This is aggravated by the fact that many of my posts are too long.

Comment: Yep, you got them.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: write out the first $P_i$s without evaluating them, and see what you get.

For the second part: see how to $Y$ changes from $x = z$ to $x = z + 1$, and turn your findings into a "recursive form".